# Create multiple nodes inside Nokogiri::XML::Builder code block using a loop

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have code that needs to loop and it will need to change the node name through the `each` loop, here is an example of what I mean:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.HasThreeNodes {
    ['Node1','Node2','Node3'].each do |name|
      xml.name "value"
    end
  }
end
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HasThreeNodes>
  <name>value</name>
  <name>value</name>
  <name>value</name>
</HasThreeNodes>
```

I have tried different variations of code, but to no avail.  I just need where it says `<name>` to be `<Node1>` and so on.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
xml.send name, "value"
```

Also why mix curlies and do/ends? It looks better if it's consistent.